# Upload Image to server location mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that allows the admin to upload Images for a store. Currenly it works locally using server path :

```
string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+ImageName); //which is local project folder.
```

When I publish it however, it no longer displays the uploaded image or uploads. How do I change the server path to store on the server, for example if the site address is www.google.com , is there a way to make this work from the server and not just locally?

Here is the full Image Upload code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,CustomerCompanyName,CustomerName,CustomerSurname,CustomerGUID,CustomerStatus,CustomerAddress,CustomerTel,CustomerCel,CustomerNumber,CustomerContact,CustomerLogo,CustomerLogoPath,LastStoreCustomerSyncID")] Customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalPath);
            string physicalFullPath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, ImageName);
            file.SaveAs(physicalFullPath);

            customer.CustomerLogo = ImageName;
            customer.CustomerLogoPath = physicalFullPath;
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

Using this to display the image in Index:

```
<td><img src=@Url.Content(@item.CustomerLogo) width="100" height="100" /></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view image, you can try like this:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(@Model.CustomerLogo)" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
```

`@Url.Content` accepts relative path.

To upload image, you can try like this:

**Model:**

```
public class FileModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**View :**

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.FileModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Upload(FileModel model)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

    model.File.SaveAs(fullPath);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I was mainly asking for a solution to upload the images on the server rather than stored in the local folder. Because when I publish the project, the upload of the image no longer works

Comment: string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName); How do I change the path so that it doesn't store locally but rather on the server

Comment: Thank you. The displaying of the Image using <img src= "@Url.Content(@Model.CustomerLogo)" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" /> doesnt work, was giving compile error when used model so I used @item.CustomerLogo instead then it gave runtime error

Comment: Try using "@Url.Content(Model.CustomerLogo)"

Comment: And I published it using your suggested upload code for the physical path but the application broke :(

Comment: @Url.Content(Model.CustomerLogo) still gives compile error

Comment: This is a working code. I have tested it. Please recheck you might be doing some small mistake